# Constructor has 2 parameters but is invoked with 1 argument

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Notifications
{
    public static Notifications Instance = new Notifications();

    public NotificationHubClient Hub { get; set; }

    private Notifications() {
        Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
"<conn string with full access>", "<hub name>");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to modify the code to pass dynamically the values of connection string and name of hub to the constructor,I changed the constructor to this:

```
private Notifications(string connectionString,string hubName) {...}
```

The problem I have now is with `Instance` ,as you can notice it's calling a constructor with no parameters,I tried to change it but it didn't work:

```
public static Notifications Instance = new Notifications(
string connectionString,string hubName);
```

What should I do to make `Instance` call the constructor and pass those two parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Instance` doesn't have access to those parameter value - it has to provide value for them!

So you can do following:

```
public static Notifications Instance = new Notifications("<conn string with full access>", "<hub name>");
```

Comment: But then `instance` will always have an instance of `Notifications` that uses same connection string and hub name, isn't? I won't be able to make a dynamic instance

Comment: Yes. I think you're facing XY problem and asking wrong questions. What are you trying to achieve with your change?

Comment: The code I posted uses a hard coded hub name and connection string,I want to change that,I want to pass their values dynamically,this is what I'm trying to achieve: `var notif = new Notifications(someSource.Con,someSource.HubName);var inst = notif.Instance;//Instance must have an object of notifications and uses con and hubname I passed` , I'm not really sure if that's possible

Comment: In that case `Instance` property is not necessary at all. Just use `notif`.

Comment: Just as I thought, I'm not even sure why `Instance` is needed/added in the first place,the code I posted is a snippet code by Microsoft  ( https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-android-notify-users/ ), I tried to understand what is the point of it but I didn't know :/

Comment: @Ala'Alnajjar in that code sample `Notifications` is designed to be a singleton, and because of that it makes sense to have `Instance` method. In your case, when you want to use different connection strings for different instances, it cannot be a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't need the Instance member altogether.  You probably simply want to use a very normal public constructor where you can then pass in your parameters.  Like this:

```
public class Notifications
{
    public NotificationHubClient Hub { get; set; }

    public Notifications(string connString, string hubName) {
        Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
        connString, hubName);
    }
}
```